# Pictures in JLabels always as big as Label

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I'm a complete n00b in Java.

I'm coming from VB.Net, so I have some expectations.

Anyways, I'm porting my VB app to Java to make it available for Mac OS and Ubuntu/Linux users.
I'd like this to be a 1-to-1 port, including the design. Which is what made me choose to use NetBeans to work with.

I've created a few labels and I've added the pictures from my resources via the designer, but they're apparently fixed in size. In VB, I could stretch the pictures so they fit snug in the labels/PictureBoxes but in Java JFrames I haven't found a way to do this.

Is there a way of doing this? If so, how?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Lg,
Beats

Comment: please add relevant code to your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I could stretch the pictures

Stretching is never really a good idea because then the images can become pixelated. There is no direct way to dynamically stretch an image in Java, you need to write custom code.

One approach would be to use Darryl's [Stretch Icon](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2012/03/31/stretch-icon/) which will allow the icon to stretch to fill the size of the label as its size changes based on the space available to the label as determined by the layout manager.

The other is to do custom painting of the image on a custom component. This is done by overriding paintComponent() and using:

```
g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), this);
```

If you want to statically scale an image after reading the image then you can use:

```
Image.getScaledInstance(...);
```

Comment: I personally have never had problems with stretching. Probably because I try to keep the aspect. But thanks for the advice. I'll check it out!

Comment: Yes, of course it depends on how large the image is and how much you stretch it.